# a custom listview java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting this exception. I cannot understand the meaning of IndexOutOfBounds. I dont know why I am getting a exception for accessing the 1th (second element) on a 0 size array. I should be able to do that, I am a iPhone developer.

```
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3101) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7025) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2589) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1791) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1518) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1789) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1518) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1789) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1518) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1789) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1518) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1789) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1518) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6904) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1864) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1526) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1262) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
05-16 09:59:11.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10208): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2143) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3486) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at com.***.**.view.PullToRefreshListView.onTouchEvent(PullToRefreshListView.java:246) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3900) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:909) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:875) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:875) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:875) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:875) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:875) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1693) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1677) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2363) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1890) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
05-17 10:02:27.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11335): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is this suppose to be?

Comment: This is suppose to be a very bad question. An example of what happens when a iphone developer gets his first exception doing android development.

Comment: @Siddharth: No supposed about it! Thanks to your reformatting, though, I can finally see that the error occurs on line 246 of the OP's PullToRefreshListView.java file.

Comment: The issue for our @android_iphone_coder is not in line 246, its before that.He is trying to do something with the 1th element, while he should not even be there if on the UI. I think he has a issue with his getSize. I go with Rachita Nanda, we need to see code. I doubt if our android_iphone_coder will bother about adding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ArrayList is empty !!As you can see its size is zero .The exception is thrown because you are trying to access 1st positioned element of a empty arrayList. Make sure  your array list is not empty to avoid this error

Comment: P.S: Post your code !!!